# What determines Source/Target Translation context in Experience Manager?

Tags: experience-manager, translation-manager

Per the [SDL Tridion Experience Manager Basic User Manual](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A395F803-E67F-466F-B2D0-46727FE43C77) (login required) authorized users can send Components to translation, within XPM, with the option to add or create a new Translation Job while selecting .

The "to/from" column in the Translation Job is based on whether you initiate translation from a Source or Target Publication.

**To be sure, what determines this "initiating" Publication context?**

*I'm assuming (hoping) it's the location of the selected Component's first localized parent "going up" (i.e. the functional equivalent to `ComponentData.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository.IdRef` as @NunoLinhares mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753289/395495)).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Source/Targets for translation are configured in the publications properties, in the Translation tab. I think that XPM refers to the publications configuration to determine the target.

I think that the context publication for content also has to be configured correctly in XPM settings.
e.g. english components are set in Content EN publication from pages in the english website publication, spanish in Content ES for the spanish website publication etc... Because this will also determine the "initiating" publication context.