# In Experience Manager, does "Translate Components" mean the Page's Component Presentations?

Tags: experience-manager, translation-manager

Somewhat related to "[What determines Source/Target Translation context in Experience Manager?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/8165/46)" I wanted to confirm how Translation Manager works in Experience Manager when choosing a Component or Page.

We can click in the border for a Component or Page in XPM to start a translation job.

To be sure, does the `Translate components` option include just the Component Presentations on the Tridion Page as it exists in the Content Manager and *not* what's visible in delivery on the Staging page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As what is different on staging via Experience Manager lives entirely in the preview database on the content delivery environment it would be impossible for Translation Manager to somehow find this content and queue it for translation; Translation Manager can only work with content that is present in the CM database as it is a pure-CM side extension.

Comment: XPM could pass the list of Components to Translation Manager. But I don't think it does that. So: improbable yes, impossible... not really. :-)

Comment: This is one of the items on a list we have. Some people refer to this list as "the backlog". :)